# React Native Expo Flatlist pull to refresh gesture not triggering on iOS but works fine on Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, mobile-development

I have a flatlist component rendered inside a flex: 1 view, that doesn't perform pull to refresh on iOS. The gesture itself doesn't work, as the list refuses to get pushed down, but works fine on Android.

Here is my flatlist code, and the only code in the screen.

```
<FlatList<any>
style={{
    flex: 1,
    // marginTop: 10,
}}
contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
data={ordersDetails?.docs}
keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
renderItem={renderItem}
bounces={false}
refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
        refreshing={loading}
        onRefresh={() => {
            fetchOrders(getOrdersListRefreshing);
        }}
    />
}
initialNumToRender={10}
onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
onEndReached={() => {
    fetchOrders(getOrdersListNoLoading);
}}
removeClippedSubviews
maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
updateCellsBatchingPeriod={200}/>;
```

renderItem is nothing but a text component.

Sorry I am a bit new to React Native.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can remove style props and containerStyle props and bounce

There is no need for a separate flex value of `flex` style. And if you put `bounce` to `false` `ios`, you can't refresh it.

Comment: can you elaborate the part regarding flex, if you dont mind?

Comment: @Biggie If you put a flex value in the style prop, there may be bugs that cannot be scrolled when the list is drawn beyond the screen.